# Flutter Firestore how to convert document content to stream

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a single document in Firestore, which holds a map of chat messages:

```
'a': { 'sentAt': '...', 'content': '...' },
'b': { 'sentAt': '...', 'content': '...' },
'c': { 'sentAt': '...', 'content': '...' },
```

I want to create a **Firestore Service** which listens to changes in that document (a new message added for example) and returns a **stream of messages** (Map<String, MessageModel>) like so:

```
Stream<Map<String, MessageModel>> getMessagesStream() {
return _firestore
    .collection('chats')
    .doc('chat')
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) =>
            ???
    );
```

}

How can I achieve that (what should be insted of the **???** there)?

This doesn't work:

```
(snapshot.data() as Map)
    .cast<String, dynamic>()
    .forEach((key, value) {
  key: MessageModel.fromJson(value);
})
```

EDIT:
Seems like this does the job:

```
  Stream<Map<String, MessageModel>> getMessagesStream() {
    return _firestore
    .collection('chats')
    .doc('chat')
    .snapshots()
        .asyncMap((snapshot) => {
              for (var message in (snapshot.data() as Map).entries)
                message.key:
                    MessageModel.fromJson(message.value)
            });
  }
```

Still not sure what is the difference between .map and .asyncMap though...
Also love to hear your thoughts about this approach (Firestore as a service etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is asyncMap

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html

```
Stream<Map<String, MessageModel>> getMessagesStream() {
return _firestore
    .collection('chats')
    .doc('chat')
    .snapshots()
    .asyncMap((snapshot) =>
            // Convert your snapshot to Map<String, MessageModel>
    );
```